# Google Analytics Universal No Events Tracked

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics

I have problems tracking events in google analytics universal.

I use following google analytics code.

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-*******-*', '*********');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

For tracking events i use following code.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', true);
```

But i cant see any events in google analytics. Am i doing something wrong or what is the problem.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The proper code is

```
ga('send', 'event', 'test1', document.URL);
```

(third argument is event name, fourth is page url).

Comment: Thanks. There is more than one way to send the event. As shown in the documentation. None of them work for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the Analytics.js [event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) documentation:

The last value should be a number

- Category **String**  Yes Typically the object that was interacted with (e.g. button)
- Action   **String**    Yes   The type of interaction (e.g. click)
- Label    **String**  No  Useful for categorizing events (e.g. nav buttons)
- Value    **Number**  No  Values must be non-negative. Useful to pass counts (e.g. 4 times)

  ga('send', 'event', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 1);

Comment: Thanks. Isnt False => 0 and True => 1? Changed it but no events shown up.

Comment: Change your `ga(...)` function to `console.log(...)` ... and check if the events are being triggered. If not, then there's error in your javascript code that's triggering the event, or maybe you' haven't set it up properly for the matched events. Also, the Analytics events take some time to show up on Google Analytics page... They don't appear until 20 minutes or so...

Comment: Ok will try this. But why there are real time events when they will not show up until 20 minutes or so?

Comment: If its a new web property remember its going to take 24 - 48 hours to start recording data.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting and testing a while, i still doesnt get it to work. It seems like google has problems with migrated universal analytics accounts and event tracking.
I see the charts jump up and down on the realtime event page but no events are shown up. Google seems to realize the events but never shows them.

When i use GA Debug (Chrome Plugin) following log message is printed. Maybe someone see a problem.

```
Running command: ga("send", "event", "button", "click", "Test") 

_j1              (&jid) 
adSenseId        (&a)   XXXXXXXXX
apiVersion       (&v)   1
clientId         (&cid) XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
eventAction      (&ea)  click
eventCategory    (&ec)  button
eventLabel       (&el)  Test
flashVersion     (&fl)  16.0 r0
hitType          (&t)   event
javaEnabled      (&je)  1
language         (&ul)  de
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
screenResolution (&sr)  1920x1080
title            (&dt)  testtes
trackingId       (&tid) UA-XXXXXXX-X
iewportSize      (&vp)  1920x394
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the image. The bars are going up and down but the events are never shown up.

[image: Example]